# Example of a function which demonstrates this equivalent condition for continuity

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, examples-counterexamples

Please note that I am not asking for a proof, just a confirmation of my understanding or a counterexample to the question I posed.

We know that a function $f:M\to N$ for $M, N$ metric spaces is continuous if it preserves sequential convergence, i.e. if $(p_n)\to p$ in $M$, then $(f(p_n)) \to f(p)$ in $N$. In a problem I am currently working on, I am asked to show a weaker condition for continuity, which is stated as follows: if $f:M \to N$ is such that for every convergent sequence $(p_n)$ in $M$ we have that the sequence $(f(p_n))$ converges in $N$, then $f$ is continuous.

From my understanding, the convergence of the image sequence $(f(p_n)) \to q\in N$ where $q$ is not necessarily equal to $f(p)$ would contradict the definition of continuity where $f$ preserves sequential convergence. So how is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how to clear the doubt without illustrating what is pretty much a proof of what you seek. Let us use your "weak" condition prove "$p_n \to p \implies f(p_n) \to f(p)$".

So suppose your function $f:M \to N$ satisfies your weaker condition.

Now let $p \in M$ and let $(p_n)$ be a sequence in $M$ converging to $p$. Then from our assumption we know that $f(p_n) \to l \in N$. Now suppose $f(p) \neq l$. Then construct a sequence $(q_n)$ like,

$$ q_n =
\begin{cases} 
p_n,  & \text{if $n$ is even} \\
p, & \text{if $n$ is odd}
\end{cases}$$

Then you will notice that $q_n \to p$ but the sequence $f(q_n)$ does not converge in $N$ contradicting our hypothesis.

Comment: So you claim that it is impossible for the sequence and its image to converge, but the function is continuous and the image of the sequence does not converge to the image of the limit?

Comment: Because if that is the case I don't see why the author would call this an improvement of  the theorem which states that $f$ preserves sequential convergence iff $f$ satisfies the $\epsilon-\delta$ condition.

Comment: If the map is continuous then the image of a convergent sequence must converge to the image of the limit. That we know. What was asked was "if a sequence $(p_n)$ in $M$ converges then the sequence $(f(p_n))$ in $N$ converges for the function $f:M\to N$, then it is continuous" which is true.

Comment: It is an improvement because the hypothesis in the problem makes no mention of the limit of $f(p_n)$. In particular in complete metric spaces if you can show that if $(p_n)$ is Cauchy then so is $f(p_n)$ then $f$ is continuous which is definitely an improvement. A nice one too actually.

Comment: So you're saying this helps to show that if we know $f$ takes cauchy sequences to cauchy sequences then it is continuous when mapping from a complete metric space into another?

Comment: Actually what we have is something stronger. If $N$ is complete, then all we need to show is that if $p_n \to p$ then $\langle f(p_n) \rangle$ is Cauchy which is kind of nice, don't you think.

Comment: Yeah that is pretty slick. So just to verify my understanding before I accept your answer (because I seemed to not grasp the subtle difference between the two statements) in both instances we are observing how the function behaves when we feed it sequences to determine continuity. The difference is that in this case we do not need to know where the image sequence converges, because if it does it must converge to the image of the limit?
And this fact allows us to make other conclusions when know certain properties about the metric spaces $f$ maps between?

Comment: Basically, yes.